# What can do with my Windows license?

Tags: windows, system-installation, windows-8

I am considering purchasing a new Dell laptop from eBay to install Ubuntu onto.  The computer comes with Windows 8 pre-installed, but I will **never be using** or needing **Windows**.

While I am aware that computers are sold with Ubuntu, they are few and far between and, as mentioned above, since the model I am planning on buying would be from a reseller (eBay), not from the manufacturer, I can't request anything special . . .

So, is there anything I can do with the Windows installation?  I would love it if there was a way to sell it, but I think that might classify as piracy.  I really hate to totally waste the part of the device's price from the manufacturer purchasing the license from Microsoft.

**Is there *something*** good or cool or fun or crazy or otherwise **beneficial to me** that I could do with this **Windows 8** license I will never really use?  Even if it's just fun?

**Any ideas?**

Comment: This is not about Ubuntu but about Windows licensing. Take it up with the UELA you got with it what you can and can not.

Comment: @Rinzwind : I guess that I have to agree with the reasoning behind on-hold vote.  I will look at the EULA in-depth to see what I can do.

Comment: You *might* be able to ask on [su]. Be sure to read their help first, and/or ask in chat.

Comment: @Seth: I did ask on SU.SE chat. Got a answer that sounded like it came from a Microsoft employee.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have the Windows product key you can sell it. You can download windows iso from microsoft website with a product key and selecting `install later by creating iso`.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only

For product key
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGhU57CHp04
http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/windows-8-product-key.htm

Note: You should never connect to internet while recovering your key on windows. That may activate your windows online.

Comment: Avoid using any (untrusted) third-party software to 'find' your **Windows 8.1** product key. Simply use **Ubuntu** command line: **`sudo hexdump -s 56 -e '/29 "%s\n"' /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM`**